# WhatsApp notifications for a specific chat while I am in it

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar, accessibility

I'm working on a notification based app, for which I need to listen to incoming notifications. By using the Accessibility Service I've been able to listen to WhatsApp notifications. However, when I am inside a specific WhatApp chat, I can`t receive notifications for this chat. I assume that this is a result of no generation of notifications by WhatApp when I am inside a chat.
Can anybody recommend on a method to receive notifications for a specific chat even if I am in it? Can this be resolved either by adding some code or by configuration of WhatApp?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, be more specific. You should provide relevant snippets of code, layouts, etc. Have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, have a detailed look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).